# how to mark the email as read using gmail api in nest js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, gmail-api

I am using Nest.js for the code, and now I am successfully fetching email data. Now, I want to individually get each email by message ID and check if the email is read or unread. If the email is unread, I want to mark it as read and update it in the database.
Anyone who know please rewrite the code for it,

---

Note: for Db i am using prisma orm

```
 // google-sheet.service.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { google } from 'googleapis';
    import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library';
    import { EnvironmentService } from 'src/core/environments/environments.service';
    import axios from 'axios';
    @Injectable()
    export class GmailService {
      constructor(private environmentService: EnvironmentService) {}
    
      async getEMails() {
        try {
          const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            this.environmentService.clientId(),
            this.environmentService.clientSecret(),
            this.environmentService.googleUri(),
          );
    
          await oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
            refresh_token:this.environmentService.refresh_token() ,
          });
    
          // fetchAll id
          const fetchingIdUrl = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/email@gmail.com/messages/`;
    
          const { token } = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
          const config: any = {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          };
    
          const response = await axios.get(fetchingIdUrl, config);
          // fetchign email by id
          const fetchingEmailById = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/eamil@gmail.com/messages/${response.data.id}`;
          const emailResponse = await axios.get(fetchingEmailById, config);
    
          const emailData = response.data;
          console.log(emailData);
    
          // emailData.payload.parts.forEach((part, index) => {
          //   if (part.body.size > 0) {
          //     const bodyContent = Buffer.from(part.body.data, 'base64').toString();
          //     console.log('Body Content:');
          //     console.log(bodyContent);
          //   }
          // });
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Error fetching emails:', err.message);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library';
import { EnvironmentService } from 'src/core/environments/environments.service';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class GmailService {
  constructor(private environmentService: EnvironmentService) {}

  async getEMails() {
    try {
      const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        this.environmentService.clientId(),
        this.environmentService.clientSecret(),
        this.environmentService.googleUri(),
      );

      await oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token: this.environmentService.refresh_token(),
      });

      // Fetch all email IDs
      const fetchingIdUrl = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/email@gmail.com/messages/';

      const { token } = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
      const config: any = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      };

      const response = await axios.get(fetchingIdUrl, config);
      const emailIds = response.data.messages.map((message: any) => message.id);

      for (const emailId of emailIds) {
        // Fetch individual email by ID
        const fetchingEmailById = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/email@gmail.com/messages/${emailId}`;
        const emailResponse = await axios.get(fetchingEmailById, config);

        const emailData = emailResponse.data;
        console.log(emailData);

        // Check if the email is unread and mark it as read
        if (!emailData.labelIds.includes('UNREAD')) {
          continue; // Skip if the email is already read
        }

        // Mark the email as read
        await markEmailAsRead(emailId, config);

        // Update the email status in the database here
        // Replace the following line with your database update logic
        console.log(`Marked email with ID ${emailId} as read.`);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching emails:', err.message);
    }
  }

  // Helper function to mark an email as read
  async markEmailAsRead(emailId: string, config: any) {
    const markAsReadUrl = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/email@gmail.com/messages/${emailId}/modify`;
    const requestBody = {
      removeLabelIds: ['UNREAD'],
    };
    await axios.post(markAsReadUrl, requestBody, config);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to replace 'email@gmail.com' with the actual Gmail account's email address you want to fetch emails from. Also, update the code inside the for loop to handle the email data and update your database accordingly. The provided code uses a helper function markEmailAsRead to mark an email as read by sending a POST request to the Gmail API.